# Column Doesn't Exist server error - but sql server management says it does

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, datatable

i'm trying to import a field from a mysql 2008 database.
I wrote this small code (that i used a few times ago) - and it keeps giving me this server error:

> Column 'Previous Login' does not belong to table Table.
>
> Line 47:         DateTime userEntry = Convert.ToDateTime(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Previous Login"]);

But it does exist! when i use the same query insql server management it works fine so i guess the return data is good , any idea where i'm going wrong?

Thank you!

```
    {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "server=(local);database=PhilipsMaterials;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    con.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    // SQL Query that returns only the messages from the last 2 weeks starting with the most recent one.
    string sql = "Select * From Messages Where DATEDIFF(DAY,Date,GETDATE()) <= 14 ORDER BY Date Desc";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
    da.Fill(ds);
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    showMsgs.DataSource = ds;
    showMsgs.DataBind();

    // new message notification
    string username = Convert.ToString(Session["username"]);
    username = username.Substring(username.IndexOf("\\") + 1);

    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    string sqluser = "Select * From [PhilipsMaterials].[dbo].[Employees] Where username='" + username + "'";
    SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sqluser, con);
    da.Fill(ds1);
    dt1 = ds1.Tables[0];
    DateTime userEntry = Convert.ToDateTime(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Previous Login"]);

    DateTime lastMsg = new DateTime();
    lastMsg = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"]);
    int compared = DateTime.Compare(userEntry, lastMsg);
    if (compared < 0) { notification.Visible = true; }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: My guess is the space is removed or translated to a different character.  Look at `ds1.Tables[0].Columns` in the debugger and see what the name is.

Comment: My experience has always been it does not like spaces in the column names.

Comment: `WHERE username='" + username + "'"` Don't do this! Never ever! Use `SqlParamter`s for this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Hi Daniel , thanks for the advice , i'll take a look but this project isn't actually going to be used on the web so security is a very low priority (needs to actually work first) :/

Answer (score 1):

If your column name contains spaces you need some kind of escaping - try using `[Previous Login]` as column name in the same way you do it in your SQL statements.

And - as mentioned in the comment to the question - have a look at [SQL injection and how to avoid it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx).

Comment: Nope , tried with the brackets even gave up and changes the column name not to have space in the middle - still same freaky error.

Comment: Okay, second attempt. Have you looked at all partial expressions of the failing line? What are `ds1.Tables[0]`, `ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]` and `ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Previous Login"]`? Are they the expected objects with the expected property values? I suggest to add an break point and closely inspect the objects using the watch window.

Comment: You have to enter the expression into the watch window - just copy and paste the expression into an empty line or select the expression in the source code, right-click and select `Add watch`.

Comment: The watch window is greyed out and right click->add watch is also greyed out. would LOVE to get this thing fixed (the debugger)

Comment: Well , i got it to work. one of those classic cases of "don't know why it doesn't work , don't now why it does work".